Is there any film of Saturn V Stage 1 falling to the ocean?
Although there were more than ten Saturn V launches and the first stage separation is clearly visible, I have never seen any tracking of the huge first stage as it fell 100 km back to the Atlantic Ocean. Why was this never filmed?

The first stage impacted over 300 miles from the launch site.

I think this question has been asked previously here or elsewhere and the answer was no (but sorry I can't remember any of the details)

Three main reasons:

You don't know exactly where it would be,
It would be dangerous to be close enough to film, and
There's not much to see from a scientific point of view.

What you're imagining is probably a building-sized tube tumbling out of the sky and hitting the water with an almighty splash.  That's not entirely inaccurate, but it's missing several important factors.
The aerodynamic forces of dropping a hollow tube from 42 miles up almost guaranteed that it would break apart on the way down, and most of those fragments would be large sheets of metal that would catch the air in unpredictable ways. They knew approximately where the heavy engines would come down on a ballistic trajectory, but "approximately" at those speeds and distances is a pretty large circle, given an uncontrolled drop through bands of high wind with uncertain aerodynamics. And even if you knew which point to go to, that point is the center of a potentially huge debris field with many pieces of falling metal being large enough to kill a person or damage a ship.
So, merely being in the vicinity is risky; you might end up being miles away from the actual impact point (and thus get a distant film of a splash, which is not much to see, or nothing at all if it's far enough to be over the horizon), and because of the breakup, you really wouldn't have a single dramatic impact to film anyway, you'd have a rain of garbage coming down all around you.
And then at the end of it all, what do you really get? Something that's marginally less interesting to look at than the test firing of a depth charge or torpedo. If there were some science to be gained then maybe they'd figure out a way to have cameras on site, but it's just not worth the expense and risk of putting a ship 350 miles out in the Atlantic to watch a rain of debris hit the water.
